# subsample, colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel in XGBClassifier() Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I've spent a good deal of time trying to find out what these "subsample", "colsample_by_tree", and "colsample_bylevel" actually did in XGBClassifier() but I can't exactly find out what they do. Can someone please explain briefly what it is they do?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check the documentation: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier ?

Comment: Actually, this XGBoost vs LightGBM documentation is very handy: https://sites.google.com/view/lauraepp/parameters. Just select the option that you are interested in in the `Parameter` drop-out menu

Answer (score 15):

The idea of "subsample", "colsample_by_tree", and "colsample_bylevel" comes from Random Forests. 
In it, you build an ensemble of many trees and then group them together when making a prediction.

The "random" part happens through random sampling of the training samples for each tree (bootstrapping), and building each tree (actually each tree's node) only considering a random subset of the attributes.

In other words, for each tree in a random forest you:

1. Select a random sample from the dataset to train this tree;
2. For each node of this tree, use a random subset of the features.
   This avoids overfitting and decorrelates the trees.

Similarly to random forests, XGB is an ensemble of weak models that when put together give robust and accurate results.
The weak models can be decision trees, which can be randomized in the same way as random forests.
In this case:

- "subsample" is the fraction of the training samples (randomly selected) that will be used to train each tree.
- "colsample_by_tree" is the fraction of features (randomly selected) that will be used to train each tree.
- "colsample_bylevel" is the fraction of features (randomly selected) that will be used in each node to train each tree.

Answer (score 2):

hope someone will find my answer helpful:

1. `colsample_bytree` - random subsample of columns when new tree **is created**
2. `colsample_bylevel` - random subsample of columns when every new **new level** is reached. I.e. you have tree with 3 levels, on 1st level A & B are chosen, on the second B & C etc.
   Note: this sampling is based on the 1st one (colsample_bytree).
3. `colsample_bynode` - random subsample of columns based on every split (left or right swerve). So, every level may have 2 different subsamples if this level has left and right split.
   Note: this sampling is based on №2 as №2 is based on №1.

Docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html

`CMND+F` the following and you'll find the part:
`colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel, colsample_bynode [default=1]`

Answer (score 1):

The parameters specify the percentage of random columns to sample from total columns available. `colsample_by` parameters work cumulatively, as each `tree` has different `levels` which end in `nodes`. The sampling can be done at each tree, level, and/or node.

If you set the sampling to 0.5, you will use half off your columns.
For example, the combination `{colsample_bytree:0.5, colsample_bylevel: 0.5, colsample_bynode:0.5}` with 64 initial features will randomly halve features used by the tree to 32, subsequently halve to 16 at the tree levels, and finally halve to 8 features at the node.

This article has a sweet and short visual explanation:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/xgboost-colsample-by-hyperparameters-explained-6c0bac1bdc1